# Check if an image is present

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `.html()` to add an image

```
$('#holder').html('<img class="holderClass" src="image.png" />');
```

Now how could I check if the image is there or not in a if statement?

I tried this but doenot work?

```
if( ! $('.holderClass') ){ 
   console.log('image.png is there');
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the `.length` of the image element:

```
if($('#holder > .holderClass').length > 0) {
   //Exists!
}
```

If you want to check for a specific image, check the `src` attribute:

```
if($('#holder > .holderClass[src="path/to/img.png"]').length > 0) {
   //Exists!
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for the false condition using `!` in your code, That's wrong.
Also for jquery object you need to check for `length` to check for existence.

```
 if($('.holderClass').length > 0){ 
   console.log('image.png is there');
 }
```

Or more specifically

```
$('#holder > .holderClass').length > 0){ 
   console.log('image.png is there');
 }
```